# Python docxtpl is not doing what it's supoust to do

Tags: python, render, docxtpl

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate


output_path = 'teste_saida.docx'
doc = DocxTemplate('teste1.docx')
context = {'Seu_nome': 'Rafael'}
doc.render(context)
doc.save(output_path)
```

This simple code, runs without any error. It generate the proper docx exit, but without the change it should have done on doc.render(context)

I try others machines, others docx archives and it keeps happens.

Comment: What does your document look like?